# Order models by a property or custom field in Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework

Am having this kind of a Model, and I wanted to order by `blog_views` property, how best can this be done.

This is the model :

```
class Post(TimeStampedModel, models.Model):
    """Post model."""
    title = models.CharField(_('Title'), max_length=100, blank=False,
                             null=False)
    # TODO: Add image upload.
    image = models.ImageField(_('Image'), upload_to='blog_images', null=True,
                              max_length=900)
    body = models.TextField(_('Body'), blank=False)
    description = models.CharField(_('Description'), max_length=400,
                                   blank=True, null=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(default=uuid.uuid4(), unique=True, max_length=100)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='posts',
                              on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    bookmarks = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='bookmarks',
                                       default=None, blank=True)
    address_views = models.ManyToManyField(CustomIPAddress,
                                           related_name='address_views',
                                           default=None, blank=True)
    likes = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='likes', default=None,
                                   blank=True,
                                   )

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-created']

    def __str__(self):
        """
        Returns a string representation of the blog post.
        """
        return f'{self.title} {self.owner}'

    @property
    def blog_views(self):
        """Get blog post views."""
        return self.address_views.all().count()
```

I read about `annotate` but couldn't get a clear picture, how can I formulate this in my view.

```
class PostList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    """Blog post lists"""
    queryset = Post.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializers.PostSerializer
    authentication_classes = (JWTAuthentication,)
    permission_classes = (PostsProtectOrReadOnly, IsMentorOnly)
    filter_backends = [filters.SearchFilter, filters.OrderingFilter]
    search_fields = ['title', 'body',
                     'tags__name', 'owner__email',
                     'owner__username'
                     ]
```

I want to filter by a property in the URL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't order by a method field because the ordering is done at the database level, and the database has no idea that, that field exists.

But you can use `annotate` like so:

```
from django.db.models import Count


class PostList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    ...
    queryset = Post.objects.annotate(address_views_count=Count('address_views')).order_by('address_views_count')
```

If you want the ordering to be optional you can use `filter_queryset`:

```
class PostList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    def filter_queryset(self, request, queryset, view):
        ordering = self.request.GET.get("ordering", None)
        if ordering == 'blog_views':
            queryset = queryset.annotate(address_views_count=Count('address_views')).order_by('address_views_count')

        return queryset
```

Comment: So , is this query done on the url level, meaning e.g I can decide to order by views like so : `http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/v1/blogs/posts/?ordering=blog_views` or have another url like so `http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/v1/blogs/posts/` without ordering, like the way the implementation of ordering works in Django ?

Comment: Edited.........

Comment: Ok thanks, but I was getting this error : 
`Cannot resolve keyword 'blog_views' into field. Choices are: address_views, address_views_count, body, bookmarks, comments, created, description, id, image, likes, modified, owner, owner_id, slug, tags, title
`

Comment: Idk, my answer doesn't contain `blog_views` as a field or variable.

Comment: This is a correct answer up to e certain point. One can expect number of `post` objects to increase (+100 K) and also the number of `address_views`. Chat obj with messages as children would be another good example.
Ordering records based of a annotated field becomes excruciating slow when the number of total objects to sort is big. So pay attention on how and where you implement this. A trade off will be a indexed model field `total_views` that is incremented on each view and order model by it on model meta.